# vba looping on excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code: -

```
Sub OverwriteMarkUp()

Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
tempHTName = Range("B4").Value
Range("AI4").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(tempHTName).Visible = True
Sheets(tempHTName).Select
Range("P3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(tempHTName).Visible = False
 

Range("Z4:Z191").ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done"
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

At the moment this VBA does what I need it to do for the first range (B4, A14 etc.).
I just need it to do the same thing for each row going down to Row 191.

Is there a easier way of doing this other than copying the VBA 191 times and change "B4" to "B5" and "AI4" to "AI5" etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is called a 'For' - 'Next' loop, I am sure Google will return plenty of results.

Answer (score 0):

While not the best code, maybe this will get you the concept... with a couple edit tips.

```vb
Sub OverwriteMarkUp()

Dim i As Integer

'don't use this, errors happen for a reason.
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'create a a loop
Dim r As Long
For r = 4 To 191

   tempHTName = Range("B" & r).Value
   Range("AI" & r).Copy

   'You don't need to hide and select the sheet to put a value on it.
   'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(tempHTName).Visible = True
   'Sheets(tempHTName).Select <- don't need this.
   'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(tempHTName).Visible = False

   'unless this is a weird date don't use paste special
   Sheets(tempHTName).Range("P3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

   'instead use...
    Sheets(tempHTName).Range("P3").Value =  Range("AI" & r).Value
   
Next r

Range("Z4:Z191").ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done"
'Exit Sub ← don't need this

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- Assigning value to a cell is more efficient than copy/paste.

```vb
Sub OverwriteMarkUp()
    Dim i As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Const LAST_ROW = 191
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    tempHTName = oSht.Range("B4").Value
    For i = 4 To LAST_ROW
        Sheets(tempHTName).Range("P" & i-1).Value = oSht.Range("AI" & i).Value
    Next
    oSht.Range("Z4:Z" & LAST_ROW).ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

---

- You can get the same output w/o looping.

```vb
Sub OverwriteMarkUp()
    Dim i As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Const LAST_ROW = 191
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    tempHTName = oSht.Range("B4").Value
    Sheets(tempHTName).Range("P3").Resize(LAST_ROW-3).Value = oSht.Range("AI4").Resize(LAST_ROW-3).Value
    oSht.Range("Z4:Z" & LAST_ROW).ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

---

- It's worth to read: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, I have tried this code but it seems to only amend the first row again. (B4, AI4). In short I have a value that I type into Z4:Z191. With a worksheet name that is within B4:B191. When I type the value into the Z column on the corresponding row I want it to copy that value into P3 on to the worksheet name that is within B4:B191.

Comment: What's on Col `AI`?  Your code copies the cell `AIx` (`Range("AI4").Copy`)

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values to Multiple Worksheets From a List

```vb
Sub OverwriteMarkUp()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = sws.Range("B4:B191") ' sheet name to READ
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srrg.EntireRow.Columns("Z") ' value to COPY
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim scell As Range, sr As Long, tws As Worksheet, tName As String
    
    For Each scell In srrg.Cells
        sr = sr + 1
        tName = CStr(scell.Value) ' READ
        On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if worksheet doesn't exist
            Set tws = wb.Worksheets(tName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not tws Is Nothing Then ' the worksheet exists
            tws.Range("P3").Value = scrg.Cells(sr).Value ' COPY
            Set tws = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        'Else ' the worksheet doesn't exist; do nothing
        End If
    Next scell
 
    scrg.ClearContents
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Markup overwritten.", vbInformation

End Sub
```